# How far does the piston extend?

Tags: space-engineers

In Space Engineers, how far, in blocks, does the piston extend when it is at its maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fully retracted, pistons are two blocks tall in their respective grids. Therefore small pistons are 1m tall and large pistons are 5m tall. Fully extended, the piston is just at 6 blocks (3m/15m) tall.

http://spaceengineers.wikia.com/wiki/Piston

Comment: Minor quibble: The pistons are actually just a bit more than 2 blocks, the heads extend into a third block - not enough to mess up visual aspects, but enough to induce Clang if you're not ready for it.